# Conditional replacing of a numeric value in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Dear all I have a data frame that looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(time=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5), type=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"), count=c(10,0,0,1,8,0,1,0,1))
df

 time type count
1    1    A    10
2    2    A     0
3    3    A     0
4    4    A     1
5    1    B     8
6    2    B     0
7    3    B     1
8    4    B     0
9    5    B     1
```

I want to examine each group of types and if I see that one count is 0 then to replace the next count forward in time with 0.  I do not count to be resurrected from the zero.

I want my data to looks like this

```
 time type count
1    1    A    10
2    2    A     0
3    3    A     0
4    4    A     0
5    1    B     8
6    2    B     0
7    3    B     0
8    4    B     0
9    5    B     0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <-
  data.frame(
    time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    type = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
    count = c(10, 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 1, 0, 1)
  )

df %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  mutate(count = if_else(lag(count, default = first(count)) == 0, 0, count))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   type [2]
#>    time type  count
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1 A        10
#> 2     2 A         0
#> 3     3 A         0
#> 4     4 A         0
#> 5     1 B         8
#> 6     2 B         0
#> 7     3 B         0
#> 8     4 B         0
#> 9     5 B         0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hello Yuriy this is a a great answer! Thank you for your time. I definitely accept and upvote the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `cummin` function.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(type) %>% mutate(count = cummin(count))

#   time type  count
#  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#1     1 A        10
#2     2 A         0
#3     3 A         0
#4     4 A         0
#5     1 B         8
#6     2 B         0
#7     3 B         0
#8     4 B         0
#9     5 B         0
```

Since `cummin` is a base R function you may also implement it in base R -

```
transform(df, count = ave(count, type, FUN = cummin))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Base R` way to do that:

```
n <- length(df$type)
df$count <- c(1,ifelse(df$type[1:(n-1)] == df$type[2:n],0,1))*df$count
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
df
  time type count
1    1    A    10
2    2    A     0
3    3    A     0
4    4    A     0
5    1    B     8
6    2    B     0
7    3    B     0
8    4    B     0
9    5    B     0
```